# How to packages wsdls?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, .net-4.0, wsdl

I have a wcf webservice, the client needs a copy of the wsdl.  However, when I open the wsdl, because of custom types, there are a bunch of xsd imports that point to my localhost.

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:50790/ ... " />
```

They need to customize their code, and want to consume the wsdl, but I'm not sure how I can package this up in a way they can properly consume the wsdl?

Is there a tool that will create a single file they can use to consume and generate their calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either the Web Services Discovery Tool (disco.exe, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs(v=vs.80).aspx ) or svcutil.exe in metadata download mode ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751847.aspx ). These can download all required WSDL/XSD files which you can then zip up and deliver to the client.